# Cant retrieve dhcp info on Android 2.2

Tags: android

I have this code working on Android 4.0.3 on the Nexus One:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE); 
        DhcpInfo info = wifi.getDhcpInfo();
        String s_gateway = String.valueOf(info.gateway); 
        String gatewayString = intToIp(Integer.parseInt(s_gateway));
        Log.d("DHCP Info: ", s_gateway+"");
        Log.d("DHCP Info: ", gatewayString+"");
```

It's return me gateway (PC + Connectify) correctly.

But the same code on Android 2.2 return 0.0.0.0. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I fixed it:

```
private String intToIp(int i) {
    return ( i & 0xFF) + "." +
        (( i >> 8 ) & 0xFF) + "." +
        (( i >> 16 ) & 0xFF) + ".1";// +
        //(( i >> 24 ) & 0xFF);
}

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    gatewayString = intToIp(ipAddress);
```